# image_picker It does not allow me to load an image from gallery or camera

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

Everything works normally, but when I click to load an image from the gallery or from the camera, it does not load the image

The message in the VSC Debug Console is:

D/MediaScannerConnection( 5069): Scanned /data/user/0/com.lot.sig/cache/ce7735c2-8d36-4633-996f-bfae03424df26527509175807023631.jpg to null

This is my user_profile.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'dart:async';
  import 'dart:io';

  import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
  import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class UserProfile extends StatefulWidget {

  UserProfile();

  @override
  _UserProfile createState() => _UserProfile();
}

enum AppState {
  free,
  picked,
  cropped,
}

class _UserProfile extends State<UserProfile> {
  AppState? state;
  File? imageFile;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    state = AppState.free;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        title: Text("Hola"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: imageFile != null ? Image.file(imageFile!) : Container(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        onPressed: () {
          if (state == AppState.free)
            _pickImage();
          else if (state == AppState.picked)
            _cropImage();
          else if (state == AppState.cropped) _clearImage();
        },
        child: _buildButtonIcon(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildButtonIcon() {
    if (state == AppState.free)
      return Icon(Icons.add);
    else if (state == AppState.picked)
      return Icon(Icons.crop);
    else if (state == AppState.cropped)
      return Icon(Icons.clear);
    else
      return Container();
  }

  Future<Null> _pickImage() async {
    final _imageFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (_imageFile != null) {
      imageFile = File(_imageFile.path);
      setState(() {
        state = AppState.picked;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<Null> _cropImage() async {
    File? croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
        sourcePath: imageFile!.path,
        aspectRatioPresets: Platform.isAndroid
            ? [
          CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
        ]
            : [
          CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio5x3,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio5x4,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio7x5,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
        ],
        androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
            toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
            toolbarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
            initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
            lockAspectRatio: false),
        iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
          title: 'Cropper',
        ));
    if (croppedFile != null) {
      imageFile = croppedFile;
      setState(() {
        state = AppState.cropped;
      });
    }
  }

  void _clearImage() {
    imageFile = null;
    setState(() {
      state = AppState.free;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And this is my image_picker_handler.dart :

```
    import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:sig/utilitary/image_picker_dialog.dart';

class ImagePickerHandler {
  late ImagePickerDialog imagePicker;
  AnimationController? _controller;
  ImagePickerListener _listener;

  ImagePickerHandler(this._listener, this._controller);

  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  openCamera() async {
    imagePicker.dismissDialog();
    var image = await (_picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera) as FutureOr<XFile>);
    cropImage(image);
  }

  openGallery() async {
    imagePicker.dismissDialog();
    var image = await (_picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery) as FutureOr<XFile>);
    cropImage(image);
  }

  void init() {
    imagePicker = new ImagePickerDialog(this, _controller);
    imagePicker.initState();
  }

  Future cropImage(XFile image) async {
    File? croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
      sourcePath: image.path,
      maxWidth: 512,
      maxHeight: 512,
    );
    _listener.userImage(croppedFile);
  }

  showDialog(BuildContext context) {
    imagePicker.getImage(context);
  }
}

abstract class ImagePickerListener {
  userImage(File? _image);
}
```